# Ajax field sometimes loses value on form submit

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a Drupal 8 form with several fields that update a price via Ajax.

One of the fields is failing to a textbox, that does a callback on the blur event. It looks like this:

```
$form['free_amount'] = array(
  '#type' => 'number',
  '#title' => $config->get('add_on_free.label'),
  '#description' => $config->get('add_on_free.description'),
  '#default_value' => '0',
  '#min' => 0,
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => $callback,
    'event' => 'blur',
    'target' => $id,
  ),
);

$form['payment']['price']['total_price'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div id="totalPrice">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#markup' => $this->t('Total amount to pay: @symbol@total', 
               ['@symbol' => $symbol, '@total' => $totalPrice]),
);
```

The ajax callback looks like this:

```
public function updateMemberPriceCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
  $ajax_response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#Pricing', $form['payment']['price']));

  return $ajax_response;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that sometimes when the form submits, the `free_amount` field has no value. It doesn't always happen, and I haven't figured out a pattern that causes it. I thought it might be if the blur event didn't occur before submitting the form, but that doesn't seem to be it. I can't see a clear pattern to when it occurs.

If I take the Ajax update off the field, it always submits correctly, but the total doesn't update before the form submits.

Is there a way I can make this work reliably?

Thanks for your help,

James

Comment: What free amount field?

Comment: Perhaps this maybe causing your empty field bug: `'#default_value' => '0',`. Currently your default value is of [type](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_datatypes.asp) string `'0'`, since this is a number field, it should just be [type](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_datatypes.asp) integer `0`, without the string quotes `''`. So make it `'#default_value' => 0,`